# Ratpack 1.7.5 how to use a proxy

Tags: ratpack

Hello dear ratpack developer, can you help me look at this problem?
Ratpack 1.7.5 cannot set the proxy,even if the global proxy is set, it does not take effect.
So how to make the URL of ratpack's http request use a proxy without changing the code or upgrading ratpack?